# How to filter the table in such a way that I get distinct records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with below details. I need to filter the table in such a way that I get distinct records. If any duplicate then consider it as once.

**Table : Student**

```
 NAME , ID , CLASS , PROJECT , EMAIL
 Viraj, 11 , A , Attendance project , viraj@gmail.com     
 Raj  , 12 , B , Student project , raj@gmail.com 
 Abhi , 13 , A , Ecommerce project , xyz@gmail.com
 Raj  , 12 , B , ABC company project , raj@gmail.com
 Sunny, 14 , C , Paper project , sunny@gmail.com 
 Abhi , 13 , A , Travelling project , xyz@gmail.com
```

If you see the ID 12, 13 are repeated twice, so combine both and display as one.

**Expected output**

[image: Expected output]

**My Query:**

```
select NAME,ID,CLASS,PROJECT,EMAIL from STUDENT group by EMAIL;
```

Answer (score 2):

We can aggregate by `ID` and then use `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT NAME, ID, CLASS,
       LISTAGG(PROJECT, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PROJECT) AS PROJECT,
       EMAIL
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY NAME, ID, CLASS, EMAIL;
```

Comment: That char(10) does not add content to new line IT on same line

Comment: Do you want all projects on the same line?  Your expected output seems to imply you want separate lines.

Comment: The projcet name should come on one after the other. For example : 2 projects data should be coming vertical one after the other in same columun

Comment: Oh...you should really handle such formatting requirements from your presentation layer, rather than at the database level.